# Create simple 9 patch image that keeps logo in centre

Tags: android, nine-patch

I am trying to create a simple 9-patch image that keeps the image in the centre.

The logo I am using is **similar** to this:

[image: Example logo]

The stretchable regions would of course be the sides and the top. The static region would the be the logo itself.

The tool I am using is the following:
https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=320&name=example

Unfortunately, no matter how much I try I just can't seem to get this right.

I can easily make the logo stay on the top right, but not in the centre.

How do I get it so the logo stays in the centre?

Can someone show me how to achieve my desired behaviour. A screenshot will be ideal!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/461/9-patch-images#t=201704040606561981592

Comment: @Saeed-rz The best I manage to get my behaviour from that doc, is how to make the logo stay on the top right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was not possible using that tool as you can only place 2 stretchable regions.

Instead I used the tool provided by the android sdk located at:

```
path-to-android-sdk/tools/lib/draw9patch.jar
```

The above tool allows you to state multiple stretchable regions.

You need 4 to achieve the centre behabiour.

One on either side of the top edge and one on either side of the left edge.